# StateListDrawable failing to parse in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout

I keep getting an error when I try to set the below statelistdrawable as a background to one of my views. I've cleaned the project and restarted Eclipse and everything but can't get it to work. I can't even get an example one from the Android developer website but that doesn't work either...

My statelistdrawable ("honeycomb.xml")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pointselector" 
        android:state_activated="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pointselectorunselect" />
</selector>
```

The error Eclipse gives me:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:178)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:832)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:769)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:208)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:731)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2450)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:371)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:364)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:84)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at (...loads of other stuff)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have same problem. Probably bug in ADT 14
Related issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21046

Answer (score 0):

place your xml file i.e **honeycomb.xml** into the drawable folder.That's enough..

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that this "@drawable/pointselector" and this "@drawable/pointselector" are present in your drawable folder I think that is your problem

you probably placed them in drawable-mdpi or something
put them in drawable folder